# How to add master on/off buttons and a heading to sub menus in the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, submenu

I need to add master on/off buttons in to sub menus in my action bar menus and small description under the title.Also I need to add heading for sub menus. I don't have idea how to do it. Do I have to use separate layout for each sub menu or else is there any way to fix using current menu.xml file? 
This is what I want to do : 
[image]

```
 This is my menu.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/settings">

             <menu >
 <item  
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:title="HEADING"/>

                <item 
                    android:id="@+id/theme"
                    android:title="theme"
                    android:showAsAction="never"
                    android:orderInCategory="1"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action2"
                    android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"/>

                 <item 
                     android:id="@+id/volunm"
                     android:title="Volumn"
                     android:orderInCategory="2"
                     android:showAsAction="never"
                     android:icon="@drawable/ic_action1"/>
     </menu> 

          </item>
     </menu>
```

This is my switch_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchForsetting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="on/off" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I'm not getting Switch button.

Answer (score 0):

Use Action provider for this. It will be easier. [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider)